# Repeating a step in a Fortran loop

Tags: fortran, fortran90, ode

I'm trying to write a Fortran 90 program to carry out Euler's method to solve ode's using an adaptive time step.

I have an `if` statement inside of a `do while` loop, in which I check that the error at each iteration of the code is less than a certain tolerance. However, if it is not less than certain tolerance, I must change a certain value (the step size) and carry out the calculation again to get a new error to compare with the tolerance.

It looks something like (and forgive me this is my first time using this website):

```
do while (some condition)
  (Get an approximation to the ODE with various subroutine calls)
  (Calculate the error)
if (error < tol)
  step = step/2
else
   step = 2*step
(Something that will return to the top of my do while loop)
end if
end do
```

Say for example, I had `do while (i < 4)`, where `i` starts at 1, and my error was not less than my tolerance, I would have to repeat the calculation again for `i=1` with a new step size.

I hope this makes sense to those of you who read this. If you need any clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no explicit counter in the `do while` loop unlike in a normal `do i=1,...` loop. you can just use `cycle` to start a new iteration. It will be the same as repeating the current iteration.  But the condition will be evaluated again. If it shouldn't be evaluated, you would have to use `go to` or restructure your code.

Or another loop nested inside the main loop might be better, but that probably counts as the restructuring mentioned above. Depends what is the condition, how you change `step` and `i` and how the tolerance depends on the `step` and `i`.

Comment: And what if it was just a normal do loop? Thanks!

Comment: It would be the same. But you must think about the counter. `Cycle` goes to the next iteration and that increases the counter. That may be good or not, it depends on your usage. Or you can always use `goto`. Or you can have a one more nested loop inside the main loop.

Comment: The problem is that you say "for example, I had do while (i < 4)" but it is not clear how you change `i` and when, so you must know what to do, we don't see it in your code.

Comment: sorry. The real code goes from 0 to 120. I increase by 0.001 each step but that number changes based on what the error in each step is. If the error is too large, I must increase by a smaller amount to try and correct the error. If the error is adequately small, I increase by a larger amount. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sort of. I would think about the nested loop.

Comment: This must be the question the professor is giving this week